# REACT event in framework7 "stepperChange" not working

Tags: reactjs, events, html-framework-7

The "stepperChange" Event does not trigger when i count up and count down.

The documentation say that there is a stepperChange Event: https://framework7.io/react/stepper.html#stepper-events

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Produkte: [
        {id:201, name:"Apple", amount: 2},
        {id:202, name:"Bananna", amount: 2}
      ]
    }
  }
  amountChanged(){
    console.log("hello world! "+Math.random());
  } 
  render(){
    return(
      <Page>
        <List>
          {this.state.Produkte.map((produkt) => {
              return(
                <ListItem key={produkt.id} title={produkt.name}>
                  <Stepper stepperChange={this.amountChanged.bind(this)} round fill value={produkt.amount} min={0} max={100} step={1} autorepeat={true} wraps={false} manualInputMode={true} decimalPoint={2}></Stepper>
                </ListItem>      
              );
          })}

        </List>
      </Page>
    );
   }
 }
```

When i click on the stepper there is now log in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, it is **onStepperChange** instead of **stepperChange**.

Comment: You are right. With _onStepperChange_ it works, and in the Examples there is also _onStepperChange_ mentioned. But in the Table above there stands _stepperChange_. Do i have to add **on** to every Event i want to use at the Attribute?

Comment: The documentation is not very clear on this...    
But i think they might be following this standard (on + event), so it would be useful to try using on + event and seeing if it works for other events.  
It looks like Javascript's onload, and onclick, it might be a hidden standard:  
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp

Comment: I found the description of this (on + event) thing. It's in the _Get Started_ Part: https://framework7.io/react/react-component-extensions.html#events